# How can I fetch data in getInitialProps in server side when using next.js with redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I'm building a web app using next.js & redux, and trying to fetch data when I refresh or visit a page by typing in the url address directly.

I put a "getItems" action in getInitialProps so that it will get triggered automatically when refreshing the page, but it never works.

If I click the "getItems" action button manually after the page refreshed, it loads data from DB so I guess the action function works fine.

But how can I fetch data automatically when refreshing a page?

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getItems } from '../../store/actions/itemAction'

const Index = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Item List</title>
      </Head>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => props.getItems()}>Get Items!</Button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

Index.getInitialProps = async ({ store }) => {
  await store.dispatch(getItems())
  return {}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  goods: state.item.goods,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getItems: () => dispatch(getItems())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which component is mounting whenever the app is refreshed, you have to make sure whatever action is fetching data is being called in the componentDidMount. For example, look at my App.js below where I call the componentDidMount:

```
   class App extends React.Component {

      componentDidMount = () => {
        this.props.persistUser()
        this.props.fetchAndSetAllPosts()
        console.log('refreshed')
      }
}
```

I imported the fetch function from my actions folder "this.props.fetchAndSetAllPosts()", which is an action fetching from an API. Every time a page is refreshed, the component mounts, therefore, should execute whatever you call in the componentDidMount. console.log() a message to be sure it's triggering properly. Let me know if this helps! Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I just found out that data get fetched in server side rendering and the data are stored in redux store properly, but the problem is that the fetched data never move to the page props after that. When I check "store.getState()", there are fetched data stored. Do you happen to know why the data never move to the page props?

Comment: Hmm, my only other suggestion would be to look at the following in your code:

 Index.getInitialProps = async ({ store }) => {
    await store.dispatch(getItems())
    return {}
}

It seems to be returning an empty object and it seems that you want it to actually return that fetched data on reload. Take a look at this link and see if it's helpful: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps

Let me know if this helps!